# automatically display the propositions with jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I implemented the autocomplete from jquery ui and it works.
The only problem is I have to push the down arrow to see the propositions
and I wanted this to do that automatically. Is this possible ?

My code so far for the autocompletion

```
function autoCompletion() {
        var splitUrl = document.URL.split('recherche');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: splitUrl[0] + "recherche/autocomplete",
            data: "auto="+$("#ville").val()
                  +"&academie_id="+$("#academie_id").val(),
            success: function(retour){
                var tags = retour.split(',');
            $("#ville").autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
                    return matcher.test( item );
                }) );
            },
            minLength: 1
            });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: set it on a `onchange` event and it should work :o

Comment: On a onchange event, I need to be outside the focus to start the query, that's why I use an onkeyup

Answer (score 0):

if you have text input and do:

```
$("#input_id").autocomplete({source: "search.php", minLength: 2, select: function(event,  ui){
    //do something here if needed after a element is select from the list. 
});
```

it should work, you just need to have `search.php` return the info.

Answer (score 0):

The order of autocomplete initialization should be reverse. The initialization of the autocomplete component should happen only once, when the page is loaded, the query should be executed automatically. See code attached:

```
  $( "#ville" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
           // Put your ajax request here
           // Put your ajax request here
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: splitUrl[0] + "recherche/autocomplete",
               data: "auto="+$("#ville").val()
                     +"&academie_id="+$("#academie_id").val(),
               success: function(your_data){
                   // Call jquery callback
                   response( your_transformed_data );
               }
           });    
        }
  });
```